# Identify when column value changes from "include" to "exclude"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a data set that looks like the below.

```
   TicketID      TicketLoggedBy        ReportingStatus
     55             3356                 Include
     56             3357                 Include
     57             4001                 Exclude
```

What I am trying to achieve is create a table separate from this one that shows only tickets that have moved from "include" to "exclude" and when the move happened.

This data is brought across nightly. So far, I have a stored procedure that gets the TicketID & ReportingStatus and compares it to the previous night load of data. If the reporting status of the first dataset = "Include" and the reporting status of the latest refresh = "exclude", then I set a flag so I can say that this status has changed to exclude. I also add a getdate() to say when it was changed.

My issue is I don't know how I can keep historic changes. The above flag is getting overwritten by the next refresh (as the status will now be exclude so it won't get set).

Ideally, the above example should look like the below:

```
   TicketID      TicketLoggedBy        ReportingStatus       ChangedToExclude       DateChanged
     55             3356                 Include                  0                 NULL
     56             3357                 Include                  0                 NULL
     57             4001                 Exclude                  1               06-Jan-2021
```

And then the next day, if ticket 57 changes back to include but ticket 55 moves to Exclude it would look like the below.

```
   TicketID      TicketLoggedBy        ReportingStatus       ChangedToExclude       DateChanged
     55             3356                 Exclude                  1               7-Jan-2021
     56             3357                 Include                  0                 NULL
     57             4001                 Include                  0                 NULL
```

And all "ChangedToExclude" flags should stay set to 1 until the status changes back to include.

Does anyone have any advice on this one? Giving me a bit of a headache trying to work it out.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the problem is here. It *seems* like you're saying that you're overwriting the value of `DateChanged` when it has a non-`NULL` value and you don't want to do that, so why not exclude rows that have a non-`NULL` value in your `UPDATE` with a `WHERE`? Or, otherwise, why not use a `CASE` expression then retain the value? Some like `CASE WHEN DateChanged IS NOT NULL THEN DateChanged WHEN {Your Boolean Expression} THEN {Expression} ELSE...`?

Comment: It's not so much "overwritten" as not re-written, so I'm gathering (because the table is dumped?). Are all these nightly loads stored in different tables?

Comment: there are 2 tables - one is a STG table and then we insert from the STG to the data table. My process runs in between the STG--> Data table to check if the data table status has changed in the STG status..

Comment: Why are you resetting the values when you don't want to? Sounds like all the info is available. Is the a `merge` or a simple `update`?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample of the logic you are looking for using the data you provided. It evaluates the status on each update and will update the fields you are looking for on each execution.

```
/*  Create Temp Tables  */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Production;
CREATE TABLE #Production
(
    TicketId INT
    , TicketLoggedBy INT
    , ReportingStatus CHAR(7)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Staging;
CREATE TABLE #Staging
(
    TicketId INT
    , TicketLoggedBy INT
    , ReportingStatus CHAR(7)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Logging;
CREATE TABLE #Logging
(
    TicketId INT
    , TicketLoggedBy INT
    , ReportingStatus CHAR(7)
    , ChangedToExclude BIT
    , DateChanged DATETIME
);

/*  Populate Production  */
INSERT INTO #Production
VALUES
    (55, 3356, 'Include')
    , (56, 3357, 'Include')
    , (57, 4001, 'Include');

/*  Populate Logging with base data  */
INSERT INTO #Logging
SELECT
    P.TicketId
    , P.TicketLoggedBy
    , P.ReportingStatus
    , 0
    , NULL
FROM
    #Production AS P;

/*  Populate Staging with Day 1 values  */
INSERT INTO #Staging
VALUES
    (55, 3356, 'Include')
    , (56, 3357, 'Include')
    , (57, 4001, 'Exclude');

/*  Populate logging with day 1 changes  */
UPDATE
    L
SET
    L.ReportingStatus = S.ReportingStatus
    , L.ChangedToExclude = IIF(L.ReportingStatus = 'Include' AND  S.ReportingStatus = 'Exclude', 1, 0)
    , L.DateChanged = IIF(L.ReportingStatus = 'Include' AND S.ReportingStatus = 'Exclude', '01/01/2022', NULL)--Change static date to GETDATE()
FROM
    #Logging      AS L
    JOIN #Staging AS S
        ON L.TicketId = S.TicketId;

/*  Output Day 1 Log  */
SELECT  * FROM  #Logging AS L;

/*  Populate Staging with Day 2 values  */
TRUNCATE TABLE #Staging;
INSERT INTO #Staging
VALUES
    (55, 3356, 'Exclude')
    , (56, 3357, 'Include')
    , (57, 4001, 'Include');

/*  Populate logging with day 2 changes  */
UPDATE
    L
SET
    L.ReportingStatus = S.ReportingStatus
    , L.ChangedToExclude = IIF(L.ReportingStatus = 'Include' AND  S.ReportingStatus = 'Exclude', 1, 0)
    , L.DateChanged = IIF(L.ReportingStatus = 'Include' AND S.ReportingStatus = 'Exclude', '01/02/2022', NULL)--Change static date to GETDATE()
FROM
    #Logging      AS L
    JOIN #Staging AS S
        ON L.TicketId = S.TicketId;

/*  Output Day 2 Log  */
SELECT  * FROM  #Logging AS L;

/*  Drop Temp Tables  */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Production;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Staging;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Logging;
```